# Interactive viewer with constrained child gets zoomed in suddenly to some scale on initial drag

Tags: flutter

I have rendered an image inside a constrained stack which is child of interactive viewer with constrained property set to false and boundary margin provided for the interactive viewer.

However, while performing pinching, the image gets scaled to fit the parent size suddenly and then only it can scaled further and also it cannot be zoomed out to default rendering. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Here' a sample code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  final TransformationController _controller = TransformationController();

  final double imageHeight = 200;
  final double imageWidth = 200;
  final double parentHeight = 500;
  final double parentWidth = 400;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: parentWidth,
            height: parentHeight,
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              minScale: 0.1,
              maxScale: 20.0,
              boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              transformationController: _controller,
              constrained:false,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: imageHeight,
                height: imageWidth,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0LE6.gif)

Expected: Need a gradual zooming behavior when performing pinching and while zooming out it must get scaled down near to default/initial rendering.

Answer (score -1):

> You can try below code :

// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, prefer_const_constructors

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DemoScreen> createState() => _DemoScreenState();
}

class _DemoScreenState extends State<DemoScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TransformationController _controller = TransformationController();
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  final double imageHeight = 200;
  final double imageWidth = 200;
  final double parentHeight = 500;
  final double parentWidth = 400;
  double _currentScale = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          _currentScale = lerpDouble(
            _currentScale,
            _controller.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis(),
            _animationController.value,
          )!;
        });
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: parentWidth,
            height: parentHeight,
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              minScale: 0.1,
              maxScale: 20.0,
              boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              transformationController: _controller,
              constrained: false,
              onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                  _currentScale = _controller.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
                });
              },
              child: GestureDetector(
                onScaleStart: (details) {
                  _animationController.reset();
                },
                onScaleUpdate: (details) {
                  double scale = _currentScale * details.scale;
                  _controller.value =
                      Matrix4.diagonal3Values(scale, scale, 1.0);
                },
                onScaleEnd: (details) {
                  double scale = _currentScale * details.scaleVelocity;
                  if (scale < 1.0) {
                    _animationController.animateTo(0.0);
                  } else if (scale > _controller.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis()) {
                    _animationController.animateTo(1.0);
                  }
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: imageHeight,
                  height: imageWidth,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the trying, using the still has a jump scaling effect on initial pinch and also the image is not draggable. My requirement is to not have the jump scale effect instead it must gradually zoom when pinching out and while pinching in, it must return to default rendering size which is the size of the image.